# how to use pointer to ostream in class

Tags: c++

I need `ostream` pointer in class which will be created at the time of construction of class.

My code is :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <map> 
#include <cstring> 
#include <climits> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

class test2_t {
    public:
        test2_t ()
        {
            std::filebuf fb;
            fb.open ("dump.txt",std::ios::out);
            ostream *output_ = new std::ostream(&fb);
        }
        virtual ~test2_t ()
        {}
        ostream *output_;
        void printing()
        {
            print(output_);
        }
        void print(ostream *out)
        {
            *out<<"dump data"<<"\n";
        }

    private:
        /* data */
};

int main( )
{
    test2_t obj;
    obj.printing();
}
```

But is getting `Segmentation fault` I don't know why. Please help me out.

Comment: Check the constructor again, don't you define a ***local variable*** with the name `output_` there? Not that it's your only problem. What do you think happens with the pointer to the other local variable `fb` when the constructor function ends? Where will that pointer point to?

Comment: [I get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8be77c35bf928360) *warning: unused variable 'output_' [-Wunused-variable]*

Comment: Do you really need a pointer? At least for this example, a member is just enough. Also, consider using `std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>` instead of the plain pointer, since `test2_t` obviously owns the stream.

Comment: `fb` is a local variable which will be destroyed when get out of the constructor. `&fb` will become dangled.

Comment: Also you have a memory leak, there's *new* but there's no *delete*. Use std::unique_ptr or just don't use a pointer: it is not needed here. Also learn to use std::ofstream.

Comment: @stijn  I will be having a file name in constructor , which I will use to open file using ostream. Please suggest, If there is any other way.

Comment: for example a member `std::ofstream outputFile;` and in the constructor use `outputFile("dump.txt")` and check if it's ok using outputFile.is_open()

Comment: @stijn Thanks! with `ofstream` I do not even need pointer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your construtor function like follows to get it working:

```
    test2_t () : output_(new std::ofstream("dump.txt")) {            
    }
```

Don't forget to release the resource in the destructor:

```
    virtual ~test2_t () {
        delete output_;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the initializer list and smart pointers? And verify the file is open?

Comment: @stijn Would be better agreed, but it's just sufficient like that.

Comment: No, it's not. Copy `test2_t` and you're hosed.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't actually explain what's wrong. Moving the construction to the initlist doesn't solve it; constructing an `ofstream` with its own inbuilt filebuf rather than using a pointer to a local filebug is what solves the segfault.

Comment: Ok, it does partially solve it as `output_` is just a name-hiding local atm. So you are a third of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You made the following mistake in your code: 
You "redeclared" your "Output"-variable in the constructor - so the pointer ios only stored in a local variable within the constructor-scope.

change this line:   ostream *output_ = new std::ostream(&fb);
into:               *output_ = new std::ostream(&fb);

In this way, the member-variable of your class is filled with the correkt pointer.

Comment: You are right, but that doesn't solve the problem entirely. Your `ostream` is still using a filebuf that's gone out of scope, and the class still leaks the stream.